# Spring Boot : Context Path in application properties giving an error

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have set up context path in my application.properties but while running the spring boot app I am getting an Error like:-
**ContextPath must start with '/' and not end with '/'**

Here is Code:-

DemoApplication :-

```
package com.ravat.demo;

import com.ravat.controller.DemoController;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.ravat.controller")
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

DemoController.java

```
package com.ravat.controller;

import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
public class DemoController {

    @RequestMapping("/index")
    public String root(){
        return "Index Page";
    }
}
```

application.properties:

```
server.port = 8085
server.context-path="/myApp"
```

But while up the server I am getting an error:-

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-10-03 09:52:23.466 ERROR 3257 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start embedded container; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ContextPath must start with '/' and not end with '/'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:137) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at com.ravat.demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:15) [classes/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'tomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/EmbeddedServletContainerAutoConfiguration$EmbeddedTomcat.class]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ContextPath must start with '/' and not end with '/'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:564) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.getEmbeddedServletContainerFactory(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:199) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.createEmbeddedServletContainer(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:162) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.onRefresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:134) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    ... 8 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ContextPath must start with '/' and not end with '/'
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AbstractConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer.checkContextPath(AbstractConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer.java:132) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AbstractConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer.setContextPath(AbstractConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer.java:120) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties.customize(ServerProperties.java:197) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:73) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizerBeanPostProcessor.java:59) ~[spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1620) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-4.3.11.RELEASE.jar:4.3.11.RELEASE]
    ... 16 common frames omitted
```

I just want that my application runs on:- **localhost:8085/myApp**

and I can access my next URL:- **localhost:8085/myApp/index**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try `server.contextPath=/myApp` and `@RequestMapping("index")`.

Comment: Thanks got it, The mistake I was doing is I put the /myApp in quotes, Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 6):

You've used quotes for the context-path. Try `server.context-path=/myApp` instead.